# On DigitalOcean App Platform, how can you get the application files?

Tags: api, digital-ocean, strapi, headless

I'm using Strapi Headless CMS to build an API quickly. Strapi achieves this by adding new files to the server. If I were doing this locally, those files would be in the API folder; however, I have no idea how to access the API folder on the DigitalOcean App Platform, let alone download my APP files if I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

When new content types are created, the resulting new files are saved in the /api folder and pushed to the git repository with each commit. The Digitalocean App platform then retrieves these new files and rebuilds the live application via automated continuous integration.

As a general rule, update content types locally and then commit the files rather than creating the content types in the live environment.